# How to create and add kjar for Drools KieScanner?

Tags: drools, kie

The goal is to add new rules to an existing session. This can be accomplished by using the KieScanner, which would update the KieContainer to a higher version based on a "kjar" and then update the session without the need to create a new one and re-establish the fact base.

Now the question is how one would create the kjars and add these to a local Maven repository with the artifacts resolvable and accessible by the KieScanner.

The examples in the official Drools repo are sadly of no help as they are geared very much towards their own needs and are of greater complexity. Nothing found on the topic and not even the documentation provides any details or gives more information than simply mentioning that it should be possible without providing a concrete example.

So how does a working and still compact/general example for the use of Drools KieScanner including the creation and adding of the kjars look like?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

"On this tutorial we will look at the use of the Drools KIE CI module, which allows us to load rules located in the different maven artefact (jar file) by using Maven Resolution strategies."

It is a bit dated, but it helped me.

https://salaboy.com/2015/10/23/back-to-basics-3-using-drools-kie-ci-continuous-integration/

Also be aware of this
[Drools Kie Scanner 7.5.0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933762/drools-kie-scanner-7-5-0-not-working)