# Drools Kie Scanner 7.5.0 not working

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

I am using Kie-CI api to scan the latest ruleset in local maven repository. Kie-CI is not working after upgrading to version 7.5.0. Below is the code I am using. Exception says artifact does not exists but actually artifact exists in repository. KJAR artifact is created using Kie-CI api. Any insights on this would be helpful.

**Code:**

```
@Async
    @Transactional
    public void scanLatestRuleset(String version){

            log.info("Request received to activate new ruleset version: [ " + version + " ]");
            KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
            ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId( "com.example", "sample-rules", version );

             //Using Kie Scanner to activate
             this.kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer( releaseId );
             KieScanner kScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner( kieContainer );
             kScanner.scanNow();
}
```

**Logs:**

```
2018-02-22 11:21:46.190 AM [ruleserviceTaskExecutor-2] INFO  com.example.service.RuleService - Request received to activate new ruleset version: [ 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT ]
2018-02-22 11:21:49.607 AM [ruleserviceTaskExecutor-2] WARN  o.a.m.integration.MavenRepository - Unable to resolve artifact: xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0.SP5
2018-02-22 11:21:49.610 AM [ruleserviceTaskExecutor-2] ERROR o.s.a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler - Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void com.example.service.RuleService.scanLatestRuleset(java.lang.String)'.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.indexArtifacts(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:409)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.setKieContainer(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:117)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieScanner(KieServicesImpl.java:227)
    at com.example.service.RuleService.scanLatestRuleset(RuleService.java:814)
    at com.example.service.RuleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5b9ebbea.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem.

This seems to be due the jar `xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0.SP5` not being in standard repositories.

As MvnRepository [states here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0.SP5), this artifact needs to be picked up from the [JBoss 3rd Party repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/) or some other repository.